# How to reduce type range

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have UserModel:

```
id: number;
email: string;
avatar: string|object;
```

User.avatar store in DB as stringified json.Then, I have next function:

```
function (user: IUserModel) {

  if (typeof user.avatar === 'string') {
    user.avatar = JSON.parse(user.avatar);
  }
  // so, on this moment user.avatar always is object
  // do sth else with user... but these operations require user.avatar to be OBJECT
  // TypeScript doesn't allow to do these operations because in IUserModel avatar could be string|object
}
```

Please, tell me how to say TypeScript that after `if` user.avatar is always object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use assertion to force the type after you are sure of what it is.

```
  if (typeof user.avatar === 'string') {
    user.avatar = JSON.parse(user.avatar);
  }

  const avatar = JSON.parse(user.avatar) as object;
```

This should then allow you to use avatar as its typed as on object.

[Type Assertion from the docs](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the type guards, they do type checking and casting in one-shot: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html